# How to set a fixed part sash container data value

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am trying to make different UI layouts for my e4 RCP application depending on the resolution. I am trying to set a fixed container data value for my parts but have no idea how to do this. Basically in the layout below I have a partstash container with a part and another partstash with two parts. I want the partstashes to be a fixed size and not resizeable. How do i achieve this? Alternatively is there a way to ensure that the content within a stash container will auto resize and always fit?

[image]

Comment: Is this an e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi) or a 3.x compatibility mode RCP?

Comment: It is  an e4 RCP my friend, I'll edit the question to state that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the tag `NoMove` to the 'Part Sash Container' containing the parts that should not be resizable.

So here:

[image]

Setting the NoMove tag prevents the child part stacks and sash container from being resized

[image]